# rails create duplicates of objects on save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `Game` that lets you select a `Character` that has many `Char_Attributes`. This character is an archetype and his attributes should not be changed. 
I want to create a new `Game`, let the player select an archetype character and then create duplicates of this characters attributes `(:game_id => game.id)`, so that the duplicate character's attributes can change during the game.

I imagine it should work somewhat like this:

```
@charattribute = Charattribute.where(:character_id => game.character.id)
@attribute.each do |attribute|
  attribute.new(:game_id => game.id, :name => attribute.name, :value => attribute.value)
end
```

But (assuming this is near to a usable syntax) where would I put this? Is this a good approach at all?

I would appreciate any tips you could give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `GameCharacter` model that belongs to your game and user, that is instantiated by the attributes of the selected archetype but has no actual relation to the archetype.

Your method would then look something like:

```
def initialise_game_character(game, archetype_character)
  game_character = GameCharacter.create(game: game)

  archetype_character.char_attributes.each do |archetype_char_attribute|
    game_character.char_attributes << CharAttribute.new(archetype_char_attribute.attributes)
  end    
end
```

This allows your `ArchetypeCharacter` attributes to be copied to `GameCharacter`.